# Need to find RadButton in Radtreelist

Tags: radtreelist

I need to find a `RadButton` in `Radtreelist`, how to do this?

```
ContentPlaceHolder contentPage = Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder2") as 
ContentPlaceHolder;
RadButton radbutton1 = (RadButton)contentPage.FindControl("RadButton1");
```

Comment: here the result is null.....as it doent find the control RadButton1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ContentPlaceHolder contentPage = this.Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1") as ContentPlaceHolder;
    RadButton R = sender as RadButton;
    RadButton radbutton1 = R.Parent.FindControl("RadButton1") as RadButton;
```